# R bookdown - cover page and appendix

Tags: r, bookdown

I have written a draft book in R Markdown.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to include a 'cover page' with graphic and text in the index.rmd file so that the rendering in bookdown- shows a cover page prior to the title page?
2. I have an appendix in the book which cover some miscellaneous thoughts and comments. Is there a way of telling bookdown not to label it as 'Chapter 11 -Appendix' but rather just Appendix?

thanks

Answer (score 17):

Yes, both is possible:

(assuming you want PDF/Latex output)

**The 1. thing you can do as follows:**

Include an `_output.yml` file in your root directory. It could look as follows:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
    before_body: frontpage.tex
```

Where you load your additional packages in `preamble.tex` and the frontpage is `frontpage.tex`.

**To do the 2. thing:**

Just add {-} behind your Chapter heading, so

```
# Appendix {-}
```

See https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#special-headers (Section 2.2.3)

For a working example have a look at:
https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo

Comment: For HTML output from bookdown, it is not straightforward to have an image before the document starts. For example, the **bookdown** book puts a cover image in the preface. For reference, there are some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60537857)

Comment: This does not work for the cover page. It inserts a blank page before the cover page. Also, the cover page does not take the full height and width of the page. It leaves out the margins.