# Add an image to Rmarkdown Bookdown output before top level heading

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

The example below (i.e. saved as a file `index.rmd` ) has the same code chunk to display an image above and below the top level heading, but the image doesn't appear above the top level heading. This occurs if there is a file **_output.yml** with only this entry `bookdown::gitbook:` in the same directory.

That line seems to enforce a table of contents (which I want) and that appears to strip out anything (image or text) before the first top level heading by default (which I don't want) - so can this behaviour be modified?

````
---
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(imager)
im <- load.image(system.file('extdata/Leonardo_Birds.jpg',package='imager'))
plot(im, axes=FALSE)
```

# R Markdown

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(imager)
im <- load.image(system.file('extdata/Leonardo_Birds.jpg',package='imager'))
plot(im, axes=FALSE)
```
````

Comment: Some options discussed [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/add-an-image-to-rmarkdown-output-to-bookdown-before-top-level-heading/53914)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What follows is workaround to your Options 2 and 3, using Markdown and CSS to style images and HTML+CSS to style text; also, using base64 image (transparent gif) generator as an space separator between elements.
Beware of whitespaces! (at the end of each line - place two white spaces and hit ENTER)
Does one of these approaches/hacks work for you? If not, it would be better to delete the answer, it may be misleading to others.

```
---
title: |
  ![](www/image.png){width=300px}|  
  |:-:|  
  ![](www/image.png){width=300px style="display: block; margin:0 auto"}  
  ![](www/image.png){width=300px height=90px align=left}  
  ![](www/image.png){width=300px height=90px align=center}  
  ![](www/image.png){width=300px height=90px align=right}  
  ![](data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==){width=150px}  
  R Markdown Title  
  <center>R Markdown Title</center>  
  <p style="text-align: right;">R Markdown Title</p>   
  ![](data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==){width=150px}
author: "Author Name"
date: "08/03/2020"
---
```

[image]

Using Markdown table to "style" images `|-| (left-aligned), |:-:| (centered) and |-:| (right-aligned)` will work well with simple RMarkdown outputs.

I realised that you have an image under `# top level heading` positioned at the very top of the page - with `top:0px`. causing image duplication and, possibly, hover problem:

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/GiViTbA.png" style="position:absolute;top:0px;height:100px;" />
```

replace with:

```
![](http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico){width=50px style="display: block; margin:0 auto;"}
```

and see what will happen.

````
---
title: |
  ![](https://i.imgur.com/GiViTbA.png){width=300px style="display: block; margin:0 auto;"}  
  ![](data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==){width=50px}  
  R Markdown Title  
  ![](data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==){width=50px}
output:
  html_document: default
---

# I'm a top level heading {-}

![](http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico){width=50px style="display: block; margin:0 auto;"}

Note, you need to replace the image with a local image if you want to show the image in the rstudio viewer.
The image will be visible in the html file created when you knit, if you open in a browser connected to the internet.

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

**EDIT**:

Let's try to find a common ground, [A Minimal Book Example](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown-demo/), github [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown).

Adjustments made in `index.Rmd`:

```
--- 
title: |
  ![](data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==){height=300px}  
author: "Author Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
---

# Prerequisites

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/GiViTbA.png" style="position:absolute;top:50px;height:300px;align:center;" /> 

This is a _sample_ book written in **Markdown**. You can use anything that Pandoc's Markdown supports, e.g., a math equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
```

`index.Rmd` output:
[image]

Adjustments made in `Chapter: Introduction` (`01-intro.Rmd`):

```
# Introduction {#intro}

![](data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==){height=240px}

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/GiViTbA.png" style="position:absolute;top:50px;height:300px;align:center;" />

You can label chapter and section titles using `{#label}` after them, e.g., we can reference Chapter \@ref(intro). If you do not manually label them, there will be automatic labels anyway, e.g., Chapter \@ref(methods).
```

`01-intro.Rmd` output:
[image]

With this solution we are "masking" a top level heading (`# Introduction`) with `.png` image, which will appear in the Table of Content as text.
*Disadvantage*: besides the obvious hack, image `width` must be at least equal or wider than top level heading title.

Comment: Thanks for the effort on this, and I see there is a lot of control via the CSS. However, the result of even a simple version based on option 2 creates another image when you hover mouse pinter over the original image (see pic [here](https://i.imgur.com/0XY39FK.png). I think creating space with `![](data:image...` then using option 3 is the best solution so far.

Comment: That second example based on *minimal bookdown* works a treat - Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Note: 3 options are provided here, and none of them are perfect. The perfect solution may rely on modifications to the **bookdown** package?

**Option 1:**
Use includes with before_body like this in your _output.yml file (suggested [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/add-an-image-to-rmarkdown-output-to-bookdown-before-top-level-heading/53914/5?u=mbn)):

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: assets/style.css
  includes:
    before_body: assets/big-image.html
    after_body: assets/footer.html
```

*Disadvantages:*
i) Requires making a html file just to insert an image.
ii) If using a web-based image, won't show in Rstudio viewer.
iii) If using a local image, path can get mixed up and won't show in online web html rendering
iv) Includes image at the top of each chapter of **bookdown** if using `before_body: my_image.html`. Alternative option `in_header: my_image.html` does not seem compatible with the sidebar index.

**Option 2**
Insert image via yaml in index.rmd, using the solution under Tip 3 *Add a Logo in your title/header/footer* at this [blog post](https://ryanpeek.github.io/2020-02-20-10-tips-to-souping-up-rmarkdown/)

```
--- 
title: |
  ![](my_image.png)  
  My title
```

*Disadvantages:*
i) When you hover over the image, it displays a copy of the image in a slightly different location (Can this "Hover" behaviour be disabled?)
ii) If using a web-based image, won't show in Rstudio viewer.
iii) If using a local image, path can get mixed up and won't show in online web html rendering

**Option 3**
The code below borrowed from [here](http://freerangestats.info/blog/2017/09/09/rmarkdown) (which you can place below the top level heading) presumably goes direct through the knitting process and inserts itself in the final html. The issue is that the image doesn't make room for itself and ends up over the first text. Is there some simple html/css to sort this out?

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/GiViTbA.png" style="position:absolute;top:0px;height:100px;" />
```

*Disadvantages:*
i) Image doesn't make room for itself and ends up over the first text. You can get around this with a hack by coding extra space (trial and error) through the yaml title like this:

```
title: |
    .      

    .  

    .  

    .  

site: bookdown::bookdown_site
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
This is superseded by Radovan's accepted answer.

This was the best answer, taking option 3 from my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60537857/4927395), and combining a code approach to making the relevant space from [Radovan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60591434/4927395).

You will still have problems if you want to include a title in the YAML (I don't need this, as my title is in the image).

Also, on first loading the page, it presents nicely, but image is not seen if you go to the top of the document using the table of contents (the `inheader` approach used by this [bookdown](https://moderndive.com/index.html) shows a better behaviour, but appears at the top of every chapter, which is not desired).

````
---
title: |
  ![](data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==){height=300px}  
output:
  html_document: default
---


# I'm a top level heading {-}
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/GiViTbA.png" style="position:absolute;top:50px;height:300px;align:center;" /> 

Note, you need to replace the image with a local image if you want to show the image in the rstudio viewer.
The image will be visible in the html file created when you knit, if you open in a browser connected to the internet.

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: So, if I got it right, you would like to have a kind of [ModernDive](https://moderndive.com/) like bookdown with each chapter having they own image on the top?

Comment: I only want an image at the top of the first chapter only, like in a book, the first thing you see is the cover image. I’m wondering if a top level heading with the book title could appear in the table of content as text, but not show in the document, just the image. Others might prefer a more general solution for a different image for each chapter above the first top level heading, though I’m not sure why you would want that.

Comment: I'm having the same logo duplication issue where the title in my index.Rmd YAML is ```title: |
    ![](cover_image.png)``` and my logo is being duplicated (see https://bookdown.org/aschmi11/RESMHandbook/). I don't really understand the solution above. Where does the data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP... come from and how does that work?

Comment: From memory, the base64 part is creating blank space, then the img source which comes later sits in the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of hovering the image duplicating the image can be fixed by removing the line below from the css file that is generated at \libs\gitbook-2.6.7\css\style.css

```
.book .book-header h1 a:hover{color:inherit;text-decoration:none}@media (max-width:1000px){.book .book-header h1{display:none}}
```

as a result, this code below places the image right above the title:

```
--- 
title: |
   ![class='btn noHover'](images/Stats.png){width=400px style="display: block; margin:0 auto; align:center;" }
   <center>GEOG380 Basic Stats with R</center>
---
```

Comment: Actually, here is a  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074546/add-image-before-bookdown-title) avoiding to modify the style.css file

Comment: I’ll test it next time I make my book. If it works, I’ll make an answer out of it, or you could if you want. Thanks for the breadcrumbs!