# Add image before bookdown title

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I'm trying to add an image before the title in gitbook style bookdown project. This is similar to [this question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/add-an-image-to-rmarkdown-output-to-bookdown-before-top-level-heading/53914) from the RStudio Community page, but I would like the image to appear only before the title, not every top-level heading.

I've created a reprex here: https://bd-reprex.netlify.app/

I've edited the `_output.yml` to include:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  ...
  includes:
    before_body: assets/logo.html
```

However, as can be seen in the example above, the image now appears before every chapter, not just before the title.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was answered [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/add-image-before-bookdown-title/67825/5).

The solution is to add a JS codeblock to the end of the `index.Rmd` file, such as

````
```{js, echo = FALSE}
title=document.getElementById('header');
title.innerHTML = '<img src="/path/to/img.png" alt="Test Image">' + title.innerHTML
```
````

Answer (score 0):

From https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-logo.html

```
title: |
  ![](logo.jpg){width=1in}   
  Adding a Logo to LaTeX Title
```

NB:  although you cannot see them, there are two trailing spaces after {width=1in}, which means a line break in Markdown. Without the line break, the image and the title would be on the same line, which may not be what you desire.

See also related question: [How to have Frontpage Image before chapter title and book title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69865807/how-to-have-frontpage-image-before-chapter-title-and-book-title)